# Upload data to the Azure ADLS Gen2 from on-premise using Python or Java

Tags: java, python, azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake

I have an Azure Storage account with Data Lake Gen2. I would like to upload data from on-premise to the Lake Gen2 file systems using Python (or Java).

I have found [examples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-file-python-getting-started) on how to interact with File Shares in the Storage account, yet I could not yet find out how to upload to the Lake (instead of the File Share). I have also found out how to do it for Gen1 Lakes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-operations-python), but nothing except closed [requests](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/22691) for Gen2.

My question is whether this is even possible with Python as of today; alternatively, how can I upload files to the Gen2 Lake using Java? A code snippet demonstrating the API calls for the upload would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the offical tutorial [`Quickstart: Upload, download, and list blobs with Python`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python), as below, you can not directly use Azure Storage SDK for Python to do any operations in Azure Data Lake Store Gen 2 if you have not enrolled in the public preview of [multi-protocol access on Data Lake Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-multi-protocol-access?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json).

> **Note**
>
> The features described in this article are available to accounts that have a hierarchical namespace only if you enroll in the public preview of [multi-protocol access on Data Lake Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-multi-protocol-access?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json). To review limitations, see the known issues article.

So the only solution to upload data to ADLS Gen2 is to use the REST APIs of ADLS Gen2, please refer to its reference [`Azure Data Lake Store REST API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/data-lake-storage-gen2).

Here is my sample code to upload data to ADLS Gen2 in Python, and it works fine.

```
import requests
import json

def auth(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret):
    print('auth')
    auth_headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    auth_body = {
        "client_id": client_id,
        "client_secret": client_secret,
        "scope" : "https://storage.azure.com/.default",
        "grant_type" : "client_credentials"
    }
    resp = requests.post(f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token", headers=auth_headers, data=auth_body)
    return (resp.status_code, json.loads(resp.text))

def mkfs(account_name, fs_name, access_token):
    print('mkfs')
    fs_headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }
    resp = requests.put(f"https://{account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/{fs_name}?resource=filesystem", headers=fs_headers)
    return (resp.status_code, resp.text)

def mkdir(account_name, fs_name, dir_name, access_token):
    print('mkdir')
    dir_headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }
    resp = requests.put(f"https://{account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/{fs_name}/{dir_name}?resource=directory", headers=dir_headers)
    return (resp.status_code, resp.text)
    
def touch_file(account_name, fs_name, dir_name, file_name, access_token):
    print('touch_file')
    touch_file_headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }
    resp = requests.put(f"https://{account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/{fs_name}/{dir_name}/{file_name}?resource=file", headers=touch_file_headers)
    return (resp.status_code, resp.text)

def append_file(account_name, fs_name, path, content, position, access_token):
    print('append_file')
    append_file_headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",
        "Content-Length": f"{len(content)}"
    }
    resp = requests.patch(f"https://{account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/{fs_name}/{path}?action=append&position={position}", headers=append_file_headers, data=content)
    return (resp.status_code, resp.text)
    
def flush_file(account_name, fs_name, path, position, access_token):
    print('flush_file')
    flush_file_headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }
    resp = requests.patch(f"https://{account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/{fs_name}/{path}?action=flush&position={position}", headers=flush_file_headers)
    return (resp.status_code, resp.text)

def mkfile(account_name, fs_name, dir_name, file_name, local_file_name, access_token):
    print('mkfile')
    status_code, result = touch_file(account_name, fs_name, dir_name, file_name, access_token)
    if status_code == 201:
        with open(local_file_name, 'rb') as local_file:
            path = f"{dir_name}/{file_name}"
            content = local_file.read()
            position = 0
            append_file(account_name, fs_name, path, content, position, access_token)
            position = len(content)
            flush_file(account_name, fs_name, path, position, access_token)
    else:
        print(result)
        
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tenant_id = '<your tenant id>'
    client_id = '<your client id>'
    client_secret = '<your client secret>'
    
    account_name = '<your adls account name>'
    fs_name = '<your filesystem name>'
    dir_name = '<your directory name>'
    file_name = '<your file name>'
    local_file_name = '<your local file name>'
    
    # Acquire an Access token
    auth_status_code, auth_result = auth(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
    access_token = auth_status_code == 200 and auth_result['access_token'] or ''
    print(access_token)
    
    # Create a filesystem
    mkfs_status_code, mkfs_result = mkfs(account_name, fs_name, access_token)
    print(mkfs_status_code, mkfs_result)
    
    # Create a directory
    mkdir_status_code, mkdir_result = mkdir(account_name, fs_name, dir_name, access_token)
    print(mkdir_status_code, mkdir_result)
    
    # Create a file from local file
    mkfile(account_name, fs_name, dir_name, file_name, local_file_name, access_token)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: is it also possible to perform a bulk upload? If I have a whole directory of files which must be uploaded for example, or a list of local paths?

Comment: Hi, Is this also possible with an existing SAS-token? So I don'tt have to put the account-key for the storage account in the code