# Bulk upload to Azure Data Lake Gen 2 with REST APIs

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake

In another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57293006/upload-data-to-the-azure-adls-gen2-from-on-premise-using-python-or-java/57303860#57303860) I had asked how to upload files from on-premise to the Microsoft Azure Data Lake Gen 2, to which an answer was provided via REST APIs. For the sake of completeness, the proposed code can be found below.

Since for large amounts of relatively small files (0.05 MB) this kind of sequentially uploading files has proven to be relatively slow, I would like to ask whether the possibility exists to perform a bulk upload for all of them at once, assuming all the paths of the files are known beforehand?

The code for uploading single files to ADLS Gen 2 using REST APIs:

```
import requests
import json

def auth(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret):
    print('auth')
    auth_headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    auth_body = {
        "client_id": client_id,
        "client_secret": client_secret,
        "scope" : "https://storage.azure.com/.default",
        "grant_type" : "client_credentials"
    }
    resp = requests.post(f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token", headers=auth_headers, data=auth_body)
    return (resp.status_code, json.loads(resp.text))

def mkfs(account_name, fs_name, access_token):
    print('mkfs')
    fs_headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }
    resp = requests.put(f"https://{account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/{fs_name}?resource=filesystem", headers=fs_headers)
    return (resp.status_code, resp.text)

def mkdir(account_name, fs_name, dir_name, access_token):
    print('mkdir')
    dir_headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }
    resp = requests.put(f"https://{account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/{fs_name}/{dir_name}?resource=directory", headers=dir_headers)
    return (resp.status_code, resp.text)

def touch_file(account_name, fs_name, dir_name, file_name, access_token):
    print('touch_file')
    touch_file_headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }
    resp = requests.put(f"https://{account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/{fs_name}/{dir_name}/{file_name}?resource=file", headers=touch_file_headers)
    return (resp.status_code, resp.text)

def append_file(account_name, fs_name, path, content, position, access_token):
    print('append_file')
    append_file_headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",
        "Content-Length": f"{len(content)}"
    }
    resp = requests.patch(f"https://{account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/{fs_name}/{path}?action=append&position={position}", headers=append_file_headers, data=content)
    return (resp.status_code, resp.text)

def flush_file(account_name, fs_name, path, position, access_token):
    print('flush_file')
    flush_file_headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }
    resp = requests.patch(f"https://{account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/{fs_name}/{path}?action=flush&position={position}", headers=flush_file_headers)
    return (resp.status_code, resp.text)

def mkfile(account_name, fs_name, dir_name, file_name, local_file_name, access_token):
    print('mkfile')
    status_code, result = touch_file(account_name, fs_name, dir_name, file_name, access_token)
    if status_code == 201:
        with open(local_file_name, 'rb') as local_file:
            path = f"{dir_name}/{file_name}"
            content = local_file.read()
            position = 0
            append_file(account_name, fs_name, path, content, position, access_token)
            position = len(content)
            flush_file(account_name, fs_name, path, position, access_token)
    else:
        print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tenant_id = '<your tenant id>'
    client_id = '<your client id>'
    client_secret = '<your client secret>'

    account_name = '<your adls account name>'
    fs_name = '<your filesystem name>'
    dir_name = '<your directory name>'
    file_name = '<your file name>'
    local_file_name = '<your local file name>'

    # Acquire an Access token
    auth_status_code, auth_result = auth(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
    access_token = auth_status_code == 200 and auth_result['access_token'] or ''
    print(access_token)

    # Create a filesystem
    mkfs_status_code, mkfs_result = mkfs(account_name, fs_name, access_token)
    print(mkfs_status_code, mkfs_result)

    # Create a directory
    mkdir_status_code, mkdir_result = mkdir(account_name, fs_name, dir_name, access_token)
    print(mkdir_status_code, mkdir_result)

    # Create a file from local file
    mkfile(account_name, fs_name, dir_name, file_name, local_file_name, access_token)
```

Comment: If you want to bulk upload a lot of files to azure data lake gen 2 with good performance, you can use python to call azcopy. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, the fastest way to upload amount of files to ADLS gen2 is using AzCopy. You can write python code to call AzCopy.

First, download AzCopy.exe as per this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#download-azcopy), after download, upzip the file, and copy the azcopy.exe to a folder(no need to install, it's an executable file), like `F:\\azcopy\\v10\\azcopy.exe`

Then generate sas token from azure portal, then copy and save the sas token:

[image]

Assume you have created filesystem for your adls gen2 account, and you don't need to create directory manually, it will create automatically by azcopy.

Another thing you need to note is, for the endpoint, you should use change **dfs** to **blob**: like change `https://youraccount.dfs.core.windows.net/` to `https://youraccount.blob.core.windows.net/`.

The sample code as below:

```
import subprocess

exepath = "F:\\azcopy\\v10\\azcopy.exe"
local_directory="F:\\temp\\1\\*"
sasToken="?sv=2018-03-28&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2019-09-20T09:44:22Z&st=2019-09-20T01:44:22Zxxxxxxxx"

#note for the endpoint, you should change dfs to blob
endpoint="https://yygen2.blob.core.windows.net/w22/testfile5/"
myscript=exepath + " copy " + "\""+ local_directory + "\" " + "\""+endpoint+sasToken + "\"" + " --recursive"

print(myscript)
subprocess.call(myscript)

print("completed")
```

The test result as below, all the files / sub-folders in local directory are uploaded to ADLS gen2:

[image]

Comment: I had implemented the for loop on my own, but the performance is very bad for large amounts of small files. I take notice however that no bulk upload feature is available in the REST APIs.

Comment: @AlexGuevara, another way is that you can use [azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json#upload-a-directory), which supports upload a folder and can provide better performance. You can use python code to call azcopy. And also updated the post with this info.