# Any way to batch-upload a set of files to ADLS gen2 storage?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I want to replace my blob storage with the ADLS Gen 2 functionality in Azure. Point is, I upload a batch of files in a build pipeline with the following command to a certain container in Blob:

```
az storage blob upload-batch \
          --destination "storage-container-files" \
          --account-name "accountname" \
          --source "./files"
```

This works perfectly fine. Now I want to do the same thing but then to Gen2 datalake, for which I have to use the `az storage blob ....` command. However I cannot find something similar to 'upload-batch', only single file upload commands. I would like not having to loop in the yaml or in a Python script.

Is there any simple way to batch upload like I could with blob?

Comment: az storage fs directory upload see my answer.

Comment: Hi Tim, any update on this issue, have your check my answer? does it answer your question?

Comment: Hi Bowman, I just tried this and it does indeed solve my issue. Accepted it as the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, there is:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'testbowman_in_AAD'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      az storage fs directory upload -f xxx/dir --account-name bowmantest -s "files" --recursive --connection-string "xxx"
```

This is my repo structure:

[image]

And successfully:

[image]

Refer to this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/fs/directory?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-fs-directory-upload

> Upload files or subdirectories to a directory in ADLS Gen2 file
> system.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any cmdlet to upload a batch of file (set of files) for ADLS gen2 Account.

We have `az storage fs file upload` cmdlet to upload a single file only.I would suggest you use [AZCOPY.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#download-azcopy) to upload bulk of files to your adls gen 2 storage account.

For additional information, you can refer to these below links:

1. [How to upload file to azure storage account using AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-upload?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json).
2. [How to upload bluk of files to adls gen2 account using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57992543/bulk-upload-to-azure-data-lake-gen-2-with-rest-apis).