# Copy files to ADLS gen2 from mobile phone

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have few files regularly created on my mobile phone. How can I upload these files on my ADLS gen2 storage account. I generally use azcopy to copy, but how can it be done on android phones

Is there a upload file rest api for ADLS gen2 or any other SDK?

Comment: [Azure Data Lake Store REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/data-lake-storage-gen2)

Comment: Is this the one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/create. How to upload a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as @GeorgeChen 's comment said. By now as I known, there is not any SDK for Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2, so the only solution is to use its REST APIs.

There is a very similar SO thread [Upload data to the Azure ADLS Gen2 from on-premise using Python or Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57293006/upload-data-to-the-azure-adls-gen2-from-on-premise-using-python-or-java/57303860#57303860) which you can refer to, my answer for it to post the Python script which defines 7 functions to help using REST APIs include `auth`, `mkfs`, `mkdir`, `touch_file`, `append_file`, `flush_file` and `mkfile`.

For using Java, you can refer to my code in Python to write your Java code with [`okhttp`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/).

---

**Update:** I reviewed Azure offical documents and searched the offical GitHub repos for ADLS Gen2, there is a public preview version of ADLS Gen2 SDK named [`Azure File Data Lake client library for Java`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-file-datalake). I see it default used the Netty HTTP client, but you can use `OkHTTP` as the [**Alternate HTTP client**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-file-datalake#alternate-http-client) as the content of `README` said, so I think you can try to use it with the alternate HTTP client `OkHTTP` for Android.

Comment: Let me try n will let u know

Comment: I can see a python library : https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-file-datalake

Comment: @Nipun Yes, I see, it's a new published release.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python

Comment: I used the new sdk and it worked for me. Thank you for your reply.